# FileNotFoundError when trying to rename all the files in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-not-found

I am writing a python script to rename all files in a given folder.  The python script exists in my `j-l-classifier` along with `images/jaguar` file.  I'm trying to run the following script to take each file in the folder and rename it to this format:

`jaguar_[#].jpg`

But its throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/onur/jaguar-leopard-classifier/file.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/onur/jaguar-leopard-classifier/file.py", line 9, in main
    os.rename(filename, "Jaguar_" + str(x) + file_ext)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '406.Black+Leopard+Best+Shot.jpg' -> 'Jaguar_0.jpg'
```

This is my code:

```
import os


def main():
    x = 0
    file_ext = ".jpg"

    for filename in os.listdir("images/jaguar"):
        os.rename(filename, "Jaguar_" + str(x) + file_ext)
        x += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `os.rename()`, you need to provide absolute paths.

I would suggest replacing line 9 with `os.rename(os.path.expanduser(f"~/{whatever folders you have here}/images/jaguar/{filename}"), os.path.expanduser(f"~/{whatever folders you have here}/images/jaguar/Jaguar_{str(x)}{file_ext}")`

`os.path.expanduser()` allows you to use the "~" syntax to aid the abs file path.

Comment: This just deleted all the files

Comment: I'm really sorry. It actually got moved to the highest folder in your tree. I forgot to put a abs file path for second arg in os.rename(), my bad. Edited it now and it should work. :)

Comment: Thanks man.  I've accepted and upvoted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Answer (score 1):

`os.listdir` only returns the filename (not the file path...)

try the following

```
for filename in os.listdir("images/jaguar"):
    filepath = os.path.join("images/jaguar",filename)
    new_filepath = os.path.join("images/jaguar","Jaguar_{0}{1}".format(x,file_ext))
    os.rename(filepath, new_filepath)
```

being explicit is almost always a path to a happier life